# Delphi 10.3.2 String Resources, when targeting Mac OS 64 bit

Tags: delphi, resources, firemonkey

I am unable to compile or use additional string resources, when targeting Mac OS 64 bit. Everything is fine for Windows 32 and 64 bit and Mac OS 32 bit.

I am adding a resource file (.res or .rc) containing a STRINGTABLE in my .dpr, but the compiler either throws an error "duplicate resource: type STRING ID XXX" or (if I change the IDs in the resource file a bit) it compiles, but LoadStr() always returns an empty string.

Comment: `STRINGTABLE` is specific to Windows, as are `.res` and `.rc` files. They're not used on OS X, iOS or Android.

Comment: Why not use `resourcestring` and let the compiler handle platform differences in how they are stored and accessed?